# Why generalized type constraints do not fully influence the compiler inside method body?

Tags: scala, implicit, type-constraints

Compiler does know type parameter `T` is a `String` inside method body because of generalised type constraint `T =:= String` in the following example

```
scala> def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A =:= String) = a.toUpperCase
def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A =:= String): String
```

however despite having this knowledge it seems it is not fully applied. For example consider how we cannot `reverse` a `String`

```
scala> def f[A <: String](a: A) = a.reverse
def f[A <: String](a: A): String

scala> def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A <:< String) = a.reverse
                                                     ^
       error: value reverse is not a member of type parameter A
```

or how we cannot assign a `String` value to `A` despite compiler knowing `A` is a `String`

```
scala> def f[A](a: String)(implicit ev: A =:= String) = { var x: A = a }
                                                                     ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : a.type (with underlying type String)
        required: A
```

What explains this behaviour, that is, why are generalised type constraints not fully effective inside method body?

Comment: For those cases, you can use the evidence itself as a cast. Remember `=:=` or `<:<: are subtypes of `Function1` so you can `ev(a).reverse`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah I see, because it is a function, then it acts as a conversion, but for `reverse` it needs to do two conversions, first from `A` to `String`, and then from `String` to `StringOps` which it cannot do automatically. Hmm, so there is nothing special about type parameter `A` when generalized-type constrained, it still remains an arbitrary type parameter inside body?

Comment: Yes, it is nothing special. Remember `<:<` are implemented in userland, the compiler doesn't know anything about them, they are just an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

In the tradition of harvesting Luis' points buried in comments, the beauty of syntactic sugar of `=:=` and `<:<` might mask the fact that there is nothing special about them. They are  similar to

```
scala> def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => String) = a.toUpperCase
def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => String): String

scala> def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => String) = ev.apply(a).reverse
def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => String): String
```

where compiler utilises evidence as implicit conversion where necessary

```
def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => String): String = 
  ev.apply(a).toUpperCase

def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => String): String = 
  Predef.augmentString(ev.apply(a)).reverse
              |              |
              |          1st conversion
        2nd conversion
```

In the case of `reverse` we cannot simply write `a.reverse` as there are two chained conversions necessary before we can call `reverse` and Scala cannot do that automatically so we need to be explicit about one step in the chain.

Viewing `A =:= String` as `A => String` we see that type parameter `A` remains unspecialised inside the method body, hence for example `var x: A = a` cannot work because `A` is not bound to any special type.